# Swift error: cannot assign value of type 'string' to subscript of type ' Track'

Tags: swift, class, dictionary

In this code below :

```
import Foundation

class Track {
    let name : String
    let instructor : String
    
    init(name : String, instructor : String) {
        self.name = name
        self.instructor = instructor
    }
}
class Student {
    let name : String
    
    init(name : String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

let tracks = [
    Track(name: "Mobile", instructor: "Bob"),
    Track(name: "Web", instructor: "Kevin"),
    Track(name: "Games", instructor: "May")
]

let students = [
    Student(name: "Harry Potter"),
    Student(name: "Hermoine Granger"),
    Student(name: "Draco Malfoy")
]

var assignments : [String : Track] = [:]
for count in students {
    print(count.name)
    var temp = count.name
    assignments[temp] = tracks[0].instructor
}
print(assignments)
```

An error code occurs on this line

```
 assignments[temp] = tracks[0].instructor
```

And it says this:

> Cannot assign value of type 'String' to subscript of type 'Track'

I have tried multiple things such as putting tracks[0].instructor in a variable and then putting that in the line of code instead but it doesn't resolve the issue. Help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It is exactly what the error says. You are trying to insert a `String` where a `Track` is expected. What are you trying to do in that line?

Comment: Change var assignments : [String : String] = [:] and you should be able to assign a String value to assignments[temp]

Answer (score 1):

`assignments` is a dictionary (`[String:Track]`)

`assignment["yourKey"]`, it's type of `Track`, you can not assign type of String to it.

I can not understand why you want to use a dictionary!!

if you want to use dictionary change `assignments:[String:Track]` to `assignments:[String:String]`